# iOS - performSegueWithIdentifier not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have only two ViewControllers in my app

Storyboard setting: -

[image]

I have a push segue directly connected from my `ViewController` to MainTableViewController.I want to my app to redirect to Main View as soon as user enters the right passcode.

Here is my code: -

```
- (IBAction)checkInput
{

    NSMutableString *aString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:firstDigit.text];
    [aString appendFormat:secondDigit.text];
    [aString appendFormat:thirdDigit.text];
    [aString appendFormat:fourthDigit.text];
    if([aString isEqualToString:@"1111"])
    {
        result.text = @"Right Password";
        //UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
        //UITableViewController *tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainTableViewController"];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
        //[self removeFromParentViewController];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else {
        result.text = @"Wrong Password";
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", aString);
}
```

`checkInput` is getting called as soon as user enters the last digit. I am calling it on `Editing did End` of my fourth TextField.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea is to embed your main view in a navigation view controller and use it as initial vc. Then present the passcode vc modaly when its needed on top of the main vc. Another advantage of this way is that you now can use `popToViewController:animated:` which you can not use this way at the moment.

```
initial vc ----> main vc
                   |
                   |
                 modaly
                   |
                   |
              pass code vc
```

Comment: That is a great idea. I applied it and working good. I present my passcode screen in viewDidLoad of MainTableViewController and dismissing it in checkInput if user enters a right passcode. Although i am still confused that is it a good practice of presenting and dismissing view controllers?

Comment: whats your concern? it it totaly normal to present vcs modaly. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

The trick is that these segues only work when your view controllers are "embedded" in a UINavigation controller. Select your first VC, then choose (from the top menu) Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller.

It should automatically set itself as the initial VC, but double check that.

Note that in this picture I am showing how, but it is already done, so you can see that it automatically connected my main VC to the Nav Controller. 
[image: Embed in Navigation Controller]

Comment: I thought about that but i don't want my user to comeback on passcode screen using Navigation Controller. I tried embedding NavigatinController between Passcode screen and Main View but still no luck. :(

Comment: If that's your intention, then you can't (or shouldn't) use a push segue. In that case you should either replace the window's rootViewController or else present it modally from the first view controller.

Comment: Thanks ctrahey for answering my question. I really appreciate it. +1